# Почему на разных компьютерах MessageBox, вызванный через WinAPI, выдает разные ошибки?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, .net-core

Для проекта есть необходимость использовать WinAPI. В процессе изучения столкнулся с методом получения ошибок Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().

Скопировал пример с сайта
[docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error?view=netcore-3.1#examples) и добавил в консольное приложение на .Net Core 5.0.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

internal class Win32
{
    // Use DllImportAttribute to inport the Win32 MessageBox
    // function.  Set the SetLastError flag to true to allow
    // the function to set the Win32 error.
    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr hwnd, String text, String caption, uint type);
}

class Program
{

    static void Run()
    {
        // Call the MessageBox with normal parameters.

        Console.WriteLine("Calling Win32 MessageBox without error...");

        Win32.MessageBox(new IntPtr(0), "Press OK...", "Press OK Dialog", 0);

        // Get the last error and display it.
        int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        Console.WriteLine("The last Win32 Error was: " + error);

        // Call the MessageBox with an invalid window handle to
        // produce a Win32 error.

        Console.WriteLine("Calling Win32 MessageBox with error...");

        Win32.MessageBox(new IntPtr(123132), "Press OK...", "Press OK Dialog", 0);

        // Get the last error and display it.

        error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        Console.WriteLine("The last Win32 Error was: " + error);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run();
    }
}
// This code example displays the following to the console:
//
// Calling Win32 MessageBox without error...
// The last Win32 Error was: 0
// Calling Win32 MessageBox with error...
// The last Win32 Error was: 1400
```

На первом компьютере все работало как должно (Ноутбук одолжил пока не купил собственный).

После покупки своего ноутбука перенес туда проект.
Тот же самый код выполняется с ошибкой: всегда после вызова messagebox возвращается ошибка 1400, но само окно появляется и возвращает 1 (IDOK).

[image: Ошибка с WinAPI]

- **Первый компьютер:**

  - Производитель: MSI GF75 Thin 10UEK;
  - Windows: Windows10 Home x64;
  - Обновление: 20H2 (KB504237);
  - BIOS: E17FSIMS.102
  - Процессор: Intel i7-10750H;
- **Второй компьютер:**

  - Производитель: HP ProBook 440 G8;
  - Windows: Windows10 Pro x64;
  - Обновление: 20H2 (KB504237)
  - BIOS: T70 Ver. 01.03.01
  - Процессор: Intel i7-1165G7

Если вызвать GetLastWin32Error до вызова messagebox - возвращается ошибка 0.

Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным? Проблема не особо серьезная, т.к. можно проверять что возвращает окно, но хотелось бы понять что происходит.

Comment: Никому не интересно какое у вас железо, всем интересен код который вы пишите, т.к. без него ничего не понятно, что и где у вас там вызывает ошибку.

Comment: Здесь не принято грубить. Здесь принято вставлять код в вопрос - _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе._ [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @aepot Вы издеваетесь да? В вопросе есть ссылка на код! ПРЯМ В ВОПРОСЕ! ЗАМЕТЕ УЖЕ! Я её даже более точной сделал, прямо на пример на странице.  У меня код 1 в 1, какой смысл тут скрины размещать? Даже тут продублирую [ССЫЛКА ИЗ ВОПРОСА](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error?view=netcore-3.1#examples)

Comment: Код должен быть не в ссылке, а в самом вопросе. Ссылку можете приложить лишь как дополнение к коду в вопросе. В вопросе кода нет.

Comment: @ArchDemon Не, ну я знал что Ru stackoverflow слабоват, но это уже прям булинг какой-то. Можно как-то администрацию пригласить?

Comment: вам @aepot указал ссылку на инструкцию по написанию хорошего вопроса. Там есть текст: *Если можете — сделайте запускаемый пример кода и дайте ссылку на сайт (например, на http://sqlfiddle.com/ или http://jsbin.com/). Обязательно добавьте тот же код и в сам вопрос. Сайт может быть недоступен для читателей, а ссылка со временем может устареть.*. Причём тут булинг ?

Comment: @ArchDemon давайте включим голову? Код 1 в 1 что в примере, вот прям символ в символ, зачем его копировать сюда? какой смысл? тяжело по ссылке перейти? Собранный вариант приложения зачем слать если проблема явно в железе? тк на одном компьютере всё хорошо, а на другом нет. И вообще, может перейдем к обсуждению проблемы? Я считаю что информации предоставлено достаточно, если можете - помогите. Спасибо!

Comment: Давайте объясню. Вот вы задали вопрос, к примеру вам ответили, и вы приняли ответ. Прошел к примеру год, и майкрософт взял и перенес свою документацию на другой адрес (заметим, что так они уже делали). Кто-то из других посетителей столкнулся с тем же вопросом и нагуглил ваш пост, нажимает ссылку, а там ничего, или переадресация на главную страницу нового сайта с документацией. В результате ваш вопрос из полезного превращается в тыкву. Но если вы вставите этот кусок кода прямо в вопрос, этого же произойдет, верно?

Comment: Хорошо, убедили, вставлю код

Comment: Спасибо, поставил плюс. Ответ знаю, сейчас немного еще потестирую, чтобы убедиться, что я ничего не попутал и напишу его.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR

> Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным? Проблема не особо серьезная, т.к. можно проверять что возвращает окно, но хотелось бы понять что происходит.

Нужно сначала проверять, что вернул метод, и только потом если результат согласно документации содержит значение соответствующее признаку ошибки, вызывать `GetLastError`. Именно в таком порядке обрабатываются ошибки Win32 API. Во всех остальных случаях результат вызова `GetLastError` нельзя считать валидным.

---

Смысл `GetLastError` в том, что он возвращает код последней ошибки, возникшей в текущем потоке. Почему у вас после вызова метода статус ошибки сохраняется - одному только майкрософту известно. Вообще должен быть 0, и мне не удалось воспроизвести вашу проблему.

Но ответ мой в другом. Обрабатывать ошибку Win32 стоит только тогда, когда метод, вызванный с атрибутом `DllImportAttribute.SetLastError == true` вернул статус, соответствующий ошибке.

Если взять конкретный `MessageBox`, то согласно [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox).

> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call [GetLastError](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror).

Ошибку стоит обрабатывать только тогда, когда он вернул `0`.

#### Как можно правильно обработать ошибку Win32

Вся сложность этой истории заключается в том, что Win32 API писалась разными людьми в разных версиях Windows в разное время. И стандарты написания кода, несмотря на очень серьезный к ним подход у Microsoft, были разные. К тому же, разные методы возвращают разные типы данных.

Поэтому придется попотеть, чтобы как-то универсально подъехать к этому вопросу. Смысл предлагаемого решения в том, чтобы поймать статус при котором надо запрашивать `GetLastError`, и если статус код соответствует индикатору ошибки, то бросать обычное исключение, содержащее код и текст ошибки.

Решение разделено на 2 части.

##### Часть 1. Атрибут, хранящий статус - индикатор ошибки

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
sealed class Win32ErrorStatusAttribute : Attribute
{
    public object ErrorStatus { get; }

    public Win32ErrorStatusAttribute(object errorStatus)
       => ErrorStatus = errorStatus;
}
```

Здесь все просто, берем что-то переданное в конструктор и кладем в свойство `ErrorStatus`.

Использовать атрибут можно вот так

```cs
internal class Win32
{
    [Win32ErrorStatus(MessageBoxResult.Error)]
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern MessageBoxResult MessageBox(IntPtr hwnd, string text, string caption, uint type);
}
```

То есть будем бросать исключение, если метод вернул `MessageBoxResult.Error`, то есть 0.

##### Часть 2. Обработка статуса и выброс исключения

Метод, который принимает выражение, преобразуемое в делегат, читает значение из атрибута, сравнивает возвращаемый статус с тем, что лежит в атрибуте. Если совпадает, то бросает [Win32Exception](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.win32exception?view=net-5.0).

```cs
public static T ThrowIfWin32Error<T>(Expression<Func<T>> exp) where T : unmanaged
{
    Win32ErrorStatusAttribute att = (exp.Body as MethodCallExpression).Method.GetCustomAttribute<Win32ErrorStatusAttribute>();
    Func<T> func = exp.Compile();
    T result = func();
    if (att == null || typeof(T) != att.ErrorStatus.GetType() || !result.Equals(att.ErrorStatus))
        return result;
    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}
```

##### Использование решения

```cs
enum MessageBoxResult // https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox#return-value
{
    Error = 0,
    Abort = 3,     // The Abort button was selected.
    Cancel = 2,    // The Cancel button was selected.
    Continue = 11, // The Continue button was selected.
    Ignore = 5,    // The Ignore button was selected.
    No = 7,        // The No button was selected.
    OK = 1,        // The OK button was selected.
    Retry = 4,     // The Retry button was selected.
    TryAgain = 10, // The Try Again button was selected.
    Yes = 6        // The Yes button was selected. 
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calling Win32 MessageBox without error...");
        MessageBoxResult result = ThrowIfWin32Error(() => Win32.MessageBox(new IntPtr(0), "Press OK...", "Press OK Dialog", 0));
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.WriteLine("Calling Win32 MessageBox with error...");
        result = ThrowIfWin32Error(() => Win32.MessageBox(new IntPtr(123132), "Press OK...", "Press OK Dialog", 0));
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
    catch (Win32Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{ex.NativeErrorCode}] {ex.Message}");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Calling Win32 MessageBox without error...
OK
Calling Win32 MessageBox with error...
[1400] Invalid window handle.
```

То есть в результате получаем поведение, похожее на родное для .NET - выброс исключения в случае ошибки.

Само собой здесь могут быть недоработки или я что-то не учёл. Сильно вдоль и поперек я код не тестировал. Просто хотел объяснить, как можно обрабатывать ошибки Windows не загромождая код.

Comment: Это не ответ на вопрос *`"Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным? .... хотелось бы понять что происходит."`* или только мне так кажется?

Comment: @avp как раз я и рассказал, что происходит. С точки зрения WinAPI, если нативный метод вернул результат, который соответствует нормальному завершению метода, а для `MessageBox` это отличный от нуля результат, то `GetLastError` вызывать вообще не следует. То есть некая аномалия, с которой столкнулся автор, не является отклонением от документированного поведения Win32 API.

Comment: Ну, т.о. ответ должен сводится к следующему  -- ***"Вызывать `GetLastError ()` нужно-можно только если предыдущая функция вернула ошибку. В остальных случаях она возвращает мусор".***

Comment: @aepot спасибо! Очень нравится реализация! Жаль только что, примеры от миктомягких, могут такую свинью подкладывать...