# как сделать так, чтобы консольное приложение c# не останавливалось при клике мышкой на консоль?

Tags: c#

У меня есть консольное приложение которое постоянно выводит данные, но при клике мышкой на консоль программа останавливается, как сделать так чтобы она продолжала работать?

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать полностью отключить возможность выделения мышью.
Если нажать правой кнопкой на заголовке окна и перейти в `Свойства` то можно увидеть галочку в чекбоксе `Выделение мышью`. Её нам и необходимо будет убрать.
[image: Свойства консоли]

Для этого создадим такой статический класс, в котором будем устанавливать или снимать эту галочку:

```
static class ConsoleQuickEdit
{
    const uint ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT = 0x0040;

    const int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, out uint lpMode);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, uint dwMode);

    internal static bool Unset()
    {
        IntPtr consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

        // Получаем текущий режим
        uint consoleMode;
        if (!GetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, out consoleMode))
        {
            // ОШИБКА: невозможно получить текущий режим
            return false;
        }

        // Очищаем бит, отвечающий за выделение мышью
        consoleMode &= ~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT;

        // Устанавливаем новый режим
        if (!SetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, consoleMode))
        {
            // ОШИБКА: Невозможно установить новый режим
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    internal static bool Set()
    {
        IntPtr consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

        // Получаем текущий режим
        uint consoleMode;
        if (!GetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, out consoleMode))
        {
            // ОШИБКА: невозможно получить текущий режим
            return false;
        }

        // Устанавливаем бит, разрешающий выделение мышью
        consoleMode |= ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT;

        // Устанавливаем новый режим
        if (!SetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, consoleMode))
        {
            // ОШИБКА: Невозможно установить новый режим
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Соответственно его нужно будет вызвать в начале работы программы:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsoleQuickEdit.Unset();

        int i=0;
        while(i<10000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i++);
        }

        ConsoleQuickEdit.Set();
        while (true)
        {
        
            Console.WriteLine(i++);
        }
    }
}
```

Во время выполнения программы, можно попробовать открыть окно свойства и проверить, что галочка с `Выделение мышью` снята.

Comment: Английский - язык сюрпризов, и внезапно противоположный глагол `Set` это не `Unset`, а `Reset`. :)

Comment: Зачем вы устанавливаете `SetLastError`, но [никак это не используете](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1306372/373567)?