# Активация Windows с помощью C#

Tags: c#, windows, cmd, key

Хочу написать своё desktop приложение, с помощью которого можно будет активировать Windows (функциональность схожа с *KMSAuto*).
Вот примерный код, который я написал:

```
        Process cmd = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", $"/c slmgr /ipk W269N-WFGWX-YVC9B-4J6C9-T83GX");
        startInfo.Verb = "runas";
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.StartInfo = startInfo;
        cmd.Start();
```

Вещи, которые мне не нравятся:

1. При выполнении когда, приложение запрашивает разрешение у пользователя на запуск консоли от имени администратора. - Как это сделать под капотом?
2. При успешной активации ключа, выводится окно (что-то похожее на MessageBox с информацией о том, что ключ был активирован). - Как это сделать под капотом?

Прикрепляю скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если специального класса в C# для работы с ключами активации не существует, тогда как скрыть происходящие процессы под капотом?
Быть может можно как-то перехватить сообщение от системы (см. пункт 2).

Также мне интересно, почему KMSAuto не запрашивает доступ от имени администратора?

Спасибо.

Comment: 1) прописать требуемые привелегии в манифест приложения и убрать `runas` 2) MessageBox из консоли? [Вот он](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1306372/373567) 3) KMSAuto совсем другое делает, он не устанавливает никаких ключей, он сбрасывает режим активации на триальную версию. И кстати без прав админа вроде не работает. 4) про капоты ничего не понял, но если надо скрыть окно консоли, то [вот так](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow) 5) отловить MessageBox до появления не получится, а после появления можно, как и любое другое окно.

Answer (score 1):

1. Нужно сделать так, чтобы само приложение запускалось с правами администратора, и убрать runas. Тогда дополнительных запросов не будет.
2. Изменить строчку `ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", $"/c slmgr /ipk W269N-WFGWX-YVC9B-4J6C9-T83GX");` на эту:

```cs
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", $"/c \"cscript //nologo %windir%\\system32\\slmgr.vbs /ipk W269N-WFGWX-YVC9B-4J6C9-T83GX\"");
```

Comment: Спасибо, как раз то, что мне было нужно!